Solving $y''+2y'+y=\frac{e^{-t}}{t^2}$ for $t>0$
I have this differential equation: $y''+2y'+y=\frac{e^{-t}}{t^2}$ for $t>0$.
To solve that I tried to follow the usual route: the associated homogeneous has solution $a_1e^{-t} + a_2te^{-t}$. I define $f(t)=\frac{e^{-t}}{t^2}$ and $g(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\Big[\frac{1}{(s+1)^2}\Big](t)=te^{-t}$ and try to evaluate
$$(f\ast g)(t)=\int_0^tg(\tau)f(t-\tau)d\tau=\int_0^t\tau e^{-\tau}\frac{e^{-(t-\tau)}}{(t-\tau)^2}d\tau= \\ =e^{-t}\int_0^t\frac{\tau}{(t-\tau)^2}d\tau=e^{-t}\Big[\ln|t-\tau|-\frac{t}{t-\tau}\Big]_0^t$$
but this diverge for $\tau \to t$. Adding the solution of the homogeneous case with the convolution I'm really close to the solution $$y(t)=c_1e^{-t}+c_2te^{-t}-e^{-t}\ln t$$ but I don't know how to handle the divergent term. How can I conclude?

That would be $g(t)$ if you presume $y(0) = y'(0) = 0$.  It doesn't seem we can make that assumption.

HINT
\begin{align*}
y'' + 2y' + y = \frac{e^{-t}}{t^{2}} & \Longleftrightarrow (e^{t}y)'' = \frac{1}{t^{2}}
\end{align*}

Ok, it's way easier this way. Thanks.
